# Auto-fill forms with the reference of one field

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am developing a website in django. I am new to django and python and need help.
I have many fields on the website and if I fill one field (ex:customer id), I want rest other fields to autocomplete from the data in the database I have.
Any help is appreciated.Thankyou...

[The website looks like in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FjjL.png)

Comment: It has little to do with django. You need javascript to populate the fields. You could create a view which accepts the customer_id as parameter and returns the needed data as json. Then you could attach onChange event to the customer_id input which makes ajax request to that view and populate the form with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You may require ajax to fetch the data for that specific customer(after the user inserts data into the field) and populate the fields with the data fetched from the backend.